# How can I determine the target type for a markup extension return value?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

I am writing a custom markup extension.
In its [`ProvideValue` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.markupextension.providevalue?view=netframework-4.7.2), I would like to modify/convert my return value based upon the intended target type of the property that the markup extension is being used to supply a value for.

(Basically, a [`TypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter) knows about the target type of its surrounding binding and can adapt its behaviour accordingly; I would like to do the same in my markup extension.)

Now, the `ProvideValue` method only receives an [`IServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider) as an argument.
It seems I should be able to use it to get an object that provides me with the desired bit of context information, but so far, none of my attempts to do so has been entirely satisfying:

- I have retrieved an `IDestinationTypeProvider` implementation. While it appears to do exactly what I need, based upon its name, unfortunately, it throws an exception:

  ```
  var dtp = (IDestinationTypeProvider)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IDestinationTypeProvider));
  var destType = dtp.GetDestinationType(); // NullReferenceException on this line
  ```
- I have retrieved an `IProvideValueTarget` implementation. It supplies me with the target property, but only as a `System.Object`, so it seems I have to prepare my code myself for treating different (?) kinds of properties and retrieving the type myself.

**What is the intended way for a markup extension to get its target type?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IServiceProvider` to get yourself an `IProvideValueTarget`, then look at `TargetProperty`, which should (but is not guaranteed to) be a `DependencyProperty`.

```
var provideValueTarget = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
var propertyType = (provideValueTarget.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty)?.PropertyType;
// Test propertyType for null
```

The target property might also be an `EventInfo` if the MarkupExtension is used with an event, or  a `MethodInfo` if it's used with an attached event (or, as you pointed out in the comments, a `PropertyInfo` if it's used with a normal property).

Unfortunately I think this is the only way of doing this. `DynamicResourceExtension` has similar checks, see [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Helper.cs,610) and [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Helper.cs,610) - if there was a better API, I assume it would be using it.

Comment: Or a `PropertyInfo` if the markup extension is used on a normal (non-dependency) property. Or something entirely else in a future version of the framework. That's kind of what I hoped the BCL would spare me of, but if this is indeed the only way, I'm going to accept this answer a bit later.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm fairly sure this is the only way of doing it unfortunately. I've added a link to some WPF code which does the same checks. If you manage to find a better way, I'll be delighted!